# Вывод соответствующей информации по клику c# uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

У меня есть GridView, в котором генерируются блоки. Содержимое блока берется вот таким образом( в коде комментами обозначила). Все отлично отрабатывает. Теперь появилась проблема с тем, что когда я кликаю по блоку( в блоке записан адрес), то отобразится( стать результатом клика)  должен именно тот элемент, который записан для данного адреса в БД. Как это можно реализовать? Была немного странная, как мне кажется, идея, но ее воплощение дало не совсем то и выводятся абсолютно все элементы.

```
public sealed partial class Details : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ForPerson> list { get; set; }
    List<ForPerson> L1;
    public Details()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var parametr = (ForPerson)e.Parameter;
        //получаем из другого файла через параметры переменные.
        var name_Person = parametr.namePerson;
        name.Text = name_Person;

        var tel_Person = parametr.telPerson;
        tel.Text = tel_Person;

        var adres_Person = parametr.adresPerson;
        adres.Text = adres_Person;

        var email_Person = parametr.emailPerson;
        email.Text = email_Person;
        //основной список,в который записаны адреса и элементы из базы, котрые им отвечают
        L1 = parametr.l1;

        Debug.WriteLine("______________" + "tut" + "________________" + name_Person + "____" + tel_Person + "_____" + adres_Person + "______" + email_Person);

        Metod();
    }

    public void Metod()
    {// всякая всячина, чтобы вывести в GridView
        list = new ObservableCollection<ForPerson>();

        foreach (ForPerson root in L1)
        {
            var T1 = root.adresD;
            var T2 = root.sostav;
            list.Add(new ForPerson { adresD = T1, sostav = T2 });

            MyGrid.ItemsSource = list;
            //отрабатывает без проблем
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++" + list.ToFormattedJsonString());
        Debug.WriteLine("_______++++++________" + "(" + L1.ToFormattedJsonString() + ")" + "________");
    }

    private void MyGrid_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {//cпособ, которым пробовала выводить элементы при нажатии на блок с адресом
        list = new ObservableCollection<ForPerson>();

        foreach (ForPerson root2 in L1)
        {
            var T1 = root2.adresD;
            var T2 = root2.sostav;
            list.Add(new ForPerson { adresD = T1, sostav = T2 });

            var res = from s in list where s.adresD == T1 select s.sostav;
            var res2 = res.ToFormattedJsonString();
            list.Add(new ForPerson { sostav = res2 });
            Debug.WriteLine("SMOTRET_____TUT_____" + res2);
            MyGrid2.ItemsSource = list;
            //но не вышло(((
        }
    }
}
```

Часть из xaml:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="402" Margin="301,330,0,-2">
    <ScrollViewer  Height="387" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <GridView x:Name="MyGrid"  Width="404" Height="387" SelectionChanged="MyGrid_SelectionChanged_1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid  Width="376" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding adresD}" Height="67" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="28" FontFamily="SF UI Display" Padding="0,10,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="389" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="568" Margin="707,332,0,-1">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="392" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="568" Margin="0,-3,0,0">
        <GridView x:Name="MyGrid2" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Zakaz" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding sostav}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="388" Width="570"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике события SelectedChanged нужно найти выбранный элемент.

```
var gridView = (GridView)sender;
var item = (GridViewItem)gridView.SelectedItem;
```

А потом сделать преобразование типа к нужному `(ВашТип)item.Content`

А вообще лучше работать через байдинг:
1) создать свойство

```
public ВашТип CurrentВашТип { get; set; }
```

2) на событие Load для страницы пропишите подсоединение вашего кодбихайнд в качестве источника данных для страницы

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

3) для вашего GridView пропишите в XAML

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentВашТип, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Теперь по выбору элемента в GridView вы будете иметь доступ к данным через свойство CurrentВашТип . Да, если вы захотите через код выбирать нужный элемент, то тогда нужно изучить что такое INotifyPropertyChanged & ObservableCollection